# leftJoin in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have two simple entities:

```
  My\Entity\Coupon:
    type: entity
    table: coupon
    id:
      id:
        type: integer
        generator:
          strategy: AUTO
    fields:
      name:
        type: string
        length: 255
            nullable: false
      value:
         type: integer
         default: 0

    My\Entity\CouponUsers:
      type: entity
      table: coupon_users
      id:
        id:
          type: integer
          length: 11
          nullable: false
          generator:
            strategy: AUTO
      fields:
            coupon_id:
          type: integer
          length: 11
          nullable: false
        user_id:
          type: integer
```

Now, I want to display simple stats for used coupons.
Running this SQL in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT c.name, count( * ) AS mycount
FROM coupon c
LEFT JOIN coupon_users u ON c.id = u.coupon_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY mycount DESC
```

Works fine as expected, returns:

```
name1    54
name2    120
```

Then, I try to do the same from Doctrine 2:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c.name, COUNT(*) as co')
    ->from('My\Entity\Coupon', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('My\Entity\CouponUsers', 'u',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'c.id = u.coupon_id')
    ->where('u.coupon_id = c.id')
    ->groupBy('c.id');

$dql = $queryBuilder->getDQL();
var_dump($dql);

SELECT c.name,
   COUNT(*) as co 
FROM My\Entity\Coupon c
LEFT JOIN My\Entity\CouponUsers u
ON c.id = u.coupon_id
WHERE u.coupon_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

So far, so good. But when I do:

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I get error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 88: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_DOT, got 'u'
```

What's wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how the Doctrine manual would suggest coding your query:

```
$querybuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select(array('c.name', 'COUNT(c.id) as co')
   ->from('My\Entity\Coupon', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('c.users', 'u')
   ->groupBy('c.id');
```

To perform this join in QueryBuilder, you'll need a bidirectional association configured between the two entities, which you don't seem to have set up yet.

I use annotations for my entities, but I think the YAML will look something like this:

```
My\Entity\Coupon:
    manyToOne:
        users:
          targetentity: CouponUsers
           inversed-by: coupon

My\Entity\CouponUsers:
    onetoMany:
       coupon:
          targetEntity: Coupon
             mapped-by: users
```

If users can have many coupons, then the relationship would be bidirectional ManyToMany instead of manytoOne/oneToMany. The details on how to configure this can be found [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

Comment: Thanks. How can I add order by `co`? Adding `->orderBy('co', 'DESC')` returns `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'co DESC': Error: 'counter' is not defined.`. The same for `->orderBy('COUNT(c.id)')`

Comment: What you typed ->orderBy('co', 'DESC') is correct and should work. Checking the obvious first: orderBy() needs to come after groupBy(), and the alias you used in select() needs to match the alias used in orderBy(). From the error message, it seems possible you may have used a different alias name. If it's still not cooperating, I'm happy to take a look at your code.